# Trying to create matrix when error Attempted to access MYAWT1(10); index out of bounds because numel(MYAWT1)=9. in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

i'm a beginner user of matlab(i would be very gratefu if you explain the solution in a simple language, consider me a 5 years old). What im trying to do is create a 21620x1 rotation matrix of a ship's motion. Since the amount of data is too many to do it manually, im trying to use the command for. Here is my code

```
MROLLT1=zeros(3,3,3)
MPITCHT1=zeros(3,3,3)
MYAWT1=zeros(3,3,3)
MR=zeros(3,3,3)
for n=1:21620
MROLLT1=[1 0 0;0 cosd(RollT1(n)) -sind(RollT1(n));0 sind(RollT1(n)) cosd(RollT1(n))]
end
for n=1:21620
MPITCHT1=[cosd(PitchT1(n)) 0 sind(PitchT1(n));0 1 0;-sind(PitchT1(n)) 0 cosd(PitchT1(n))]
end
for n=1:21620
MYAWT1=[cosd(YawT1(n)) -sind(YawT1(n)) 0;sind(YawT1(n)) cosd(YawT1(n)) 0;0 0 1]
end
for n=1:21620
MR=MYAWT1(n)*MPITCHT1(n)*MROLLT1(n)
end
```

When i run the program, there is an error like this

```
Attempted to access MYAWT1(10); index out of bounds because numel(MYAWT1)=9.
Error in Ship_Reference_Frame_Integration_R1 (line 40)
MR=MYAWT1(n)*MPITCHT1(n)*MROLLT1(n)
```

Could you please explain to me how to create rotation matrix(MR) for every data from data 1 to data 21620?
And by the way, a source in another post told me that i should create matrix with command 'zeros'(as in the above code) to define the matrix. What does it mean?

Comment: The error is quite simple: you're creating a 3x3x3 matrix (9 elements) and you're trying to access element 10. If you want 21620 elements, create 216020 elements like `zeros(1,21620)`. The documentation for `zeros` is [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zeros.html).

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm. Actually, whatis the purpose of creating zero matrix with command zeros before actually calculate the matrix itself? Is it to define the size of matrix? And if yes, why do we have to define that?

Comment: It's [preallocation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html) of the memory required for the array. It provides better performance than growing the array each time you add a new element. It's a good habit to get into.